Can I change a member variable of a struct using a std::map value?
There is a structure that has multiple const char* member variables.
typedef struct WWCryptoAuthorizationHeader
{
    int age;
    const char *name;
    const char *address;
} StudentInfo;

There is a function that takes a (pointer to) this struct and a (C-style) string containing the name of one of the member variables. Within this function, I create a map from member names to their values. Then I find the provided member name in the map. Can I have the function change the designated member of the struct using the value from the map?
I tried the following
void foo(StudentInfo *studentInfo, const char* key)
{
    std::map<std::string, const char*> studentInfoMap;
    
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("name", studentInfo->name));
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("address", studentInfo->address));

    for(auto &item : studentInfoMap)
    {
       if (strcmp(key, item.first.c_str()) == 0)
       {
          item.second = "John";
       }
    }
}

but *studentInfo was not updated.

Is there a reason why you are using const char* instead of std::string in the struct? Also, there is no point in using a for loop if you already know the exact key you are looking for, just use map::operator[] or map::at() instead.

not 100% clear what you're asking, but if you're asking "can I search for the field called 'name' or 'address' in a StudentInfo object during runtime and change it?", the answer is no. The names of the fields are not retained during runtime. But in the code above, looks like you're successfully reassigning item.second to "John" to me. Are you expecting something in studentInfo to change?

Note: If you're headed anywhere near where I think you may be headed, you might be interested in pointers to members.

@yano Yes, I would like to see studentinfo changed at runtime.

You are storing a copy of the value of your const char* pointers into your map, so you are not able to update the original pointers inside the StudentInfo struct.  You would have to store the address of the pointers instead, eg:
void foo(StudentInfo *studentInfo, const std::string &key)
{
    std::map<std::string, const char**> studentInfoMap;
    
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("name", &(studentInfo->name)));
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("address", &(studentInfo->address)));

    for(auto &item : studentInfoMap)
    {
       if (key == item.first)
       {
          *(item.second) = "John";
       }
    }
}


That being said, the for loop is unnecessary. You can use map::operator[] or map::at() to access an element by its key, eg:
void foo(StudentInfo *studentInfo, const std::string &key)
{
    std::map<std::string, const char**> studentInfoMap;
    
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("name", &(studentInfo->name)));
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("address", &(studentInfo->address)));

    *(studentInfoMap[key]) = "John";
    // or
    *(studentInfoMap.at(key)) = "John";
}


You should also consider using std::string instead of const char* inside of your struct, eg:
struct StudentInfo
{
    int age;
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

void foo(StudentInfo *studentInfo, const std::string &key)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string*> studentInfoMap;
    
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("name", &(studentInfo->name)));
    studentInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair("address", &(studentInfo->address)));

    *(studentInfoMap[key]) = "John";
    // or
    *(studentInfoMap.at(key)) = "John";
}


You are so kind
It helped me a lot.
